# Mayan-EDMS not working with default values of Redis

Tags: docker, redis, mayanedms

The following is the Mayan-EDMS [`docker-compose.yaml`](https://gitlab.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms/-/raw/master/docker/docker-compose.yml) redis part

```
redis:
    command:
      - redis-server
      - --appendonly
      - "no"
      - --databases
      - "2"
      - --maxmemory
      - "100mb"
      - --maxclients
      - "500"
      - --maxmemory-policy
      - "allkeys-lru"
      - --save
      - ""
      - --tcp-backlog
      - "256"
      - --requirepass
      - "${MAYAN_REDIS_PASSWORD:-mayanredispassword}"
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    networks:
      - bridge
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${MAYAN_REDIS_VOLUME:-redis}:/data
```

and the following is my project docker-compose.yaml redis part:

```
  redis:
    container_name: "redis-app"
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    networks:
      - abc
```

I am trying to rid of the mayan-edms redis part, because of my our project already has the redis container and I wanted to use that only for redis. For this I changed the Mayan celery env to this `MAYAN_CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://redis:6379/0` and backend too respective. but when I am starting the mayan-edms app (`docker-compose up app`), the logs keep goes in the loop

```
app_1         | Waiting for redis:6379
app_1         | Waiting for redis:6379
app_1         | Waiting for redis:6379
app_1         | Waiting for redis:6379
app_1         | Waiting for redis:6379
app_1         | Waiting for redis:6379
app_1         | Waiting for redis:6379
```

I am missing something while setting up mayan-edms?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.